# How to make a Splunk Dashboard dynamic?

Tags: splunk, splunk-dashboard

I have a query lets call it query1 that looks at sales and I have storenumber=1 in that query  I have query2 that looks at returns with storenumber=1 in the second query

I want to add these queries to my store's dashboard. Now in the dashboard, I want to have a box (text, dropdown, anything) where I can enter a new store number and run both those queries.

If I enter say 2 in that box how does that 2 get replaced in the queries where store number =1 to be storenumber=2 now?

I thought it would be some token like variable? but I'm not sure how to get that to work so that the number entered is populated where the storenumber= is in the queries?

Any help will be appreciated
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *is* a token-like variable.  When you create your input (dropdown, text, etc.) is it given a name.  The value of that input is referenced simply by putting the token name within `$`s.

```
... | where storenumber = $store$ | ...
```

Comment: Ok thanks. And I Eric the query one I add to the dashboard with the token name?

Comment: I don't grok that question.

Comment: Yikes that was a typo. My question was. Once I add the queries to the dashboard I would make the token and then modify the queries to add the token $token name here$  where I had store number hard coded.